# how chaplin renders model after fetch?, how the view know that the fetch as finished?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, chaplinjs

I'm doing a sample proyect based on Chaplin-boilerplate, and is working perfect, but I can't understand how the view render after the fetch has finalized, for example with Backbone you can use on event change, or with a callback in the fetch method, but with chaplinjs how are doing this?, are there using the event change from Backbone?, what class of Chaplinjs is binding the event ? how are doing the binding ?

```
class CampaignController extends Chaplin.Controller

  title: 'Campaign'
    index: (params) ->
    campaign = new Campaign()
    @view = new CartView model: campaign


class CartView extends View
  template: template
  template = null
  container: '#cart'
  autoRender: true
  className: 'cart'
  initialize: ->
    super
  render: ->
    super

class Campaign extends Model

  initialize: (attributes, options) ->
    super
    @urlRoot = "http://localhost/store/js/test-data/cart.json"
    @fetch()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you're doing `@view = new CartView model: campaign` you're assigning the `campaign` object as the model to the view.
The ChaplinJS View class automatically does the following:

```
if (target === 'model' || target === 'collection') {
  prop = this[target];
  if (prop) {
    this.listenTo(prop, eventName, callback);
  }
}
```

This should answer your question

Answer (score 0):

I would put your fetch logic to the controller:

```
class Campaign extends Model
    urlRoot = "http://localhost/store/js/test-data/cart.json"

Campaign = require 'models/Campaign'
class CampaignController extends Chaplin.Controller

  title: 'Campaign'
    index: (params) ->
    campaign = new Campaign()
    campaign.fetch
       success:
          @view = new CartView model: campaign
       error:
           console.error('sorry dude')


class CartView extends View
  template: template
  template = null
  container: '#cart'
  autoRender: true
  className: 'cart'
  initialize: ->
    super
  render: ->
    super
```